# Get the logged user in AuthenticationFacade

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am following tutorial to get the User and I created a facade class

```
@Component
public class AuthenticationFacade implements IAuthenticationFacade {

@Override
public User getAuthentication() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

    return (User) authentication.getDetails();
}
```

}

In my service class I am trying to get the logged user with

```
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
User loggedUser = authenticationFacade.getAuthentication();
```

But  I get the exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ssssseeee.services.tool.security.TokenBasedUserDetails cannot be cast to org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
```

Tried a lot of things to cast authentication to user, to get the details to get the Principal object but I cannot figure out how to cast to this user type

Comment: Your stack trace clearly shows `TokenBasedUserDetails` can not cast to `User`. So instead of returning `User` object return `TokenBasedUserDetails` object.

Comment: @SudhirOjha I tried casting TokenBasedUserDetails to User, but it does not let me. I also tried to just create new User and set manually every property but then I get Cannot pass null or empty values to constructor (IllegalArgumentException) which is the password being null

Comment: If `com.ssssseeee.services.tool.security.TokenBasedUserDetails` is set to contain user info, why do you expect something else?

Answer (score 1):

Change this `User loggedUser = authenticationFacade.getAuthentication();` into `TokenBasedUserDetails  loggedUser = (TokenBasedUserDetails )authenticationFacade.getAuthentication();` then use `loggedUser` methods to retrive information about the current logged user.

Comment: Yes I tried this as well but if I try create User and set its fields I cannot set the password since it is not kept in memory Cannot pass null or empty values to constructor